# algorithm to convert any string to a real number between -1 and 1

Tags: algorithm, encoding, computer-science, decoding

Hi i'm looking for a an algorithm to convert any finitely large set of finitely long set of string to a specific real number between -1 and 1, in which every string would have a unique real number representation.
This question is programming language agnostic.

Where each string could contain numerous words and end lines, and real number by mathematical definition. I could also use arbitrary precision libraries.

Comment: A string can already be considered a real number, represented in base-256 (assuming 8-bit characters).  So there's nothing that needs doing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If you conveniently assume that the string stops just before the first `'\0'`, which is not very language-agnostic.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Not sure I follow.

Comment: I updated the question to clear my ambiguity

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am only pointing out that `"\0"` and `"\0\0"` are different strings but are the same number in base 256 in the straightforward interpretation. But if you exclude `'\0'` from the characters that can be part of a string, then the interpretation of strings as base-256 numbers is injective.

Comment: You could compute an integer hash and transform the value from [intmin .. intmax] to [-1.0 .. + 1.0]. But such a hash would not be necessarily unique

Comment: Since no computer can represent every real number, since no computer has unlimited memory, what practical use does this question have? This is a forum about programming, not mathematics.

Comment: @PhilFrost yes, it may not have applicability for infinite length strings, but we couldn't store those anyway. It has definite uses for finitely long strings. For example, see the accessibility keyboard, [Dasher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dasher), which would not be possible without it.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Aha, I see.  That's a fair point.  Well, I guess you could work in base-257, and have no character that maps to 0...

Comment: arbitrary precision libraries still can't represent real numbers, because their precision is bounded by available memory. For example, how would they represent pi, or e, except by a special value that represents exactly pi or e? This works for real numbers we have named, but that's not all of them. As ceykooo hints, you will have to change your question to "any _finitely large_ set of _finitely long_ strings" for it to have an answer that could be implemented on a computer.

Comment: @PhilFrost true i will reword the question as such

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want each string to map to a unique real number, which can also be decoded back into the original string, I would use [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding).

Basically, what you want to do is divide the set of real numbers between -1 and 1 into a number of parts equal to the number of characters in your alphabet, `n`. To encode a single character string, just pick the start of one of these regions. To encode the second character of the string, first find the region where the first character lies, and then subdivide that region into `n` smaller regions, and pick the region where the second character falls. You can then recurse on this solution to to be able to convert arbitrary length strings into unique real numbers.

For example, lets say our alphabet is only the characters `a` and `b` and we want to encode the string `aba`. The first `a` gives us the region `[-1,0)`, the second character then subdivides this region, and yields `[-0.5,0)`. Repeat with the final `a` to yield the region `[-0.5,-0.75)`. *Any* number in this region can *only* be decoded to the sequence `aba` (given that we know the length of the original string, or we can just recurse forever when decoding).

(See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) for a more detailed explanation of the encoding and decoding process. Note that you are probably only interested in equal-size regions for this problem.)

Answer (score 6):

[*Turning my comment into an answer.*]

You don't need to do anything.  A string can already be considered a real number.  Each character is a digit after the radix point, in base-256 (for 8-bit chars).

[As pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115648/algorithm-to-convert-any-string-to-a-real-number-between-1-and-1/14115812#comment19535783_14115648), this fails to distinguish strings that have multiple trailing `\0` characters.  If this is a concern, then you could instead consider this number base-257, and have no character map to a value of 0.

As there is no algorithm, there are no extra memory requirements; your input string is also your output!  There are no issues with arbitrary-precision libraries, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose a string is 20 ASCII bytes, or 160 bits. A double-precision real number has only 64 bits. So there cannot be a unique real number for each possible string.

On the other hand, if you are not limited to 64 bits, just put the decimal (binary) point after the first bit, take the first bit as sign, and take all the bits of the string as fraction.

In fact, if you limit your alphabet to digit characters 0-9, it already exists, in the form of decimal arithmetic, as supported in COBOL and prior languages and old IBM computers.
Just put the decimal point in front, multiply by 2, and subtract 1.

Comment: won't this only give me an integer greater than 1? and Yes there are plenty of arbitrary precision libraries out there for me to use , no restriction on that.

Comment: This assumes that "\0\0" and "\0" are not strings, or that it is not important to distinguish them.

Comment: @pyCthon: If the first string, in binary is 0.11111.... it is +1 minus epsilon. If it is 1.0000......1 it is -1 plus epsilon.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: You can map characters any way you like onto bits, and then assume any string consists of some number of non-zero bit codes, followed by an infinite string of zero-bits codes.

Comment: this is assuming a language with limited reals.  There's quite a few with arbitrary precision